# How to display the Refs Section on some frames?

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I am using the online LaTeX editor for the presentation preparing.

I need to add the References Section into the frame(s). I have tried two variants:

The first attempt is:

```latex
\section{References} 
\begin{frame}{\insertsection}
\bibliography{refs.bib} 
\end{frame}
```

In this case, the References were added into one frame and I don't see the full list of references.

The second attempt is:

```latex
\section{References}
\bibliography{refs.bib}
```

In this case, the References were added into three frames, I see the full list of references. But I have the problems with page numeration and the reference split to two frames.

[image]
**Question.** How to write down the References Section correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I added the options `allowframebreaks`

```latex
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks] {\insertsection}
\framesubtitle{\insertsubsection}
\bibliography{refs.bib}
\end{frame}
```